# iPhone Safari offline-cache manifest not working correctly

Tags: iphone, caching, mobile-safari, manifest, offline

I'm working on a mobile site for the iphone. I've added a cache manifest and loaded it with a list of resources needed for offline capability. The manifest file has the correct content type. You can view the manifest file in the header of this page:

http://www.rvddps.com/apps/sixshot/booking.html

I had a bunch of links to pages but due to my user level i'm only allowed to post one link. You can see the manifest file there and the source code of the page i'm trying to cache.

I've set the correct MIME type on the server, but the cache only seems to work occasionally.. not all the time. I've tried following apples' official caching guidelines as well.

Can anyone point out where i'm going wrong?

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the manifest file and found 'Â' characters in some of the blank lines. What text editor are you using? Make sure you use the proper encoding and line ending types.

Comment: I just used text edit for mac. how do i view these to take them out?

Comment: I've taken out those characters now... still no luck though.. any other thoughts?

Comment: I don't know. I checked on my mac and it appears that it is caching booking.html, but the javascript and css files are getting loaded from the server.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the problem now.. i wish i knew how i did. Thanks for the help.